# prevent returned data from PHP to being printed twice by JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my JS checks if a youtube link exists on my textarea. i send the URL to a PHP file that echoes the URL back to JS, and append the result.

the issue im having, the returned data is being printed (or appended) in my case, **twice**.

if i typed-in a youtube link `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iol0B-clFFM` in my textarea, i send this link to **getyoutube.php** with status `200 OK`

```
Request URL:<website> /getyoutube.php?url=youtube.com/watch?v=iol0B-clFFM
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview 
url:youtube.com/watch
```

---

*PHP file* just echoes the URL, and this is the response i get from  it.

[image]
[image]

---

this result will be fetched by JS and append this result to an html element. but the data being appended is being printed twice

[this is my JS]

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var youtube = //regex
    var getUrl = $('#url');

    getUrl.keyup(function() {
      if  (youtube.test(getUrl.val())) {
      var youtube_url = getUrl.val().match(youtube)[0];

      $.post("./includes/getyoutube.php?url="+ youtube_url, {
         }, function(response){
         $('.echotest').append(response);
      });       
      }
});
```

**tldr: send data to a php file via POST, and echo back the data. the data is being printed twice by my JS.**

[update]

i added `alert(response)` and im getting 2 alerts. one after the other. it appears my `success function` is being looped twice? not sure why.

Comment: console.log(response); ?

Comment: Perhaps keyUp is triggered twice for some reason. Store URL and compare to previous to make sure it's not same.

Comment: @samitha i get blank. what data should i be expecting to see?

Comment: @user1933824 How does it blank if it appended ?

Comment: Did you put the `console.log` *inside* `function(response){…}`?

Comment: yes i did. `function(response){$('.echotest').append(response);console.log(response);}` but nothing appears.. but the `response` from php file is being appended on my html.

Comment: BTW, in this case, as you're manually appending URL parameters to the URL, you should use `encodeURIComponent` and then replace all instances of `%20` by `+`. It's easier to add the parameter to the second parameter of `$.post` and let jQuery do the conversion for you.

Comment: That sounds weird; are you sure you looked in the console? It cannot happen that something is appended to your HTML markup but doesn't show up in the console.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel thanks for the `encodeURIComponent` tip ill keep that in mind.

Comment: i have added `alert(response)` and i get 2 alerts one after the other.

Comment: Do you have a test page, so we can have a look?

Comment: sure, here you go http://camppablo.com/curl/ just put any youtube vids.

Comment: change keyup function to keydown. could be work

Comment: @DeepakManwal it didn't worked :(

Comment: Oh sorry but its all fault of event you have to change it with your suitable.

Comment: I think your event should be **keypress**: then a character will be inserted. If you use keyup and e.g. paste a link in it, a keyup event will be generated after releasing `V` *and* after releasing `Ctrl`.

Comment: Can you include a non-minified version of jQuery, that's way more convenient when debugging. And please remove that call to `alert`, it's very annoying, the result is just popping up in the console, too.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel removed `alert`, changed `keyup` to `getUrl.keypress(function() {` when i insert some text in the textfield and pressed enter. data is being submitted to PHP and no data is repeated unless i hit enter again.

Comment: i think youre right, when i hit `ctrl` and `v` it produces 2 actions. is there any way i could limit that? and also, ive included non minified jquery

Comment: Yes, use `keypress` instead of `keyup`, as I explained.

Comment: i do know the difference of keypress and keyup, but the purpose of that input box is to actually input data without hitting enter. but, let me just try first the `paste` event, and see how it works.

Comment: Another work around would be by starting a timeout whenever a user releases a key and wait e.g. 1 second before changing the UI. If another keyup event is fired within that second, don't do anyting but resetting the timer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `keyup` event, an event if fired on *every* keyup-motion, even when releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Use `keypress` instead.

If you want to fire an event when some text is pasted in your `input`, use the [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.onpaste) event.